# Prometheus series api call fails if there is a condition in the query

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to make a prometheus api call using series api, it is failing with the below error

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "errorType": "bad_data",
  "error": "parse error at char 83: could not parse remaining input \"\u003e 0\"..."
}
```

The query being executed is

```
kube_pod_status_ready{pod=~"cougar-prod-batch-646b68475-dqhrw", condition="true"}  == 0
```

The api call is

```
https://prometheus.xxx/api/v1/series?match[]=kube_pod_status_ready%7Bpod%3D~%22cougar-prod-batch-646b68475-dqhrw%22%2C%20condition%3D%22true%22%7D%20%3E%200&start=1521003903&end=1521025503
```

Comment: Hi sir... I am desperate and curious to ask a question... Does this reputation helps me to get the job?? Please answer

Answer (score 1):

The series match API takes a selector, not a full PromQL expression. You probably want the [query API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries).

Comment: I'm trying to use it within grafana(within a variable query) to list all matching pod names.

Comment: You want to use `query_result` then and extract the labels with a regex, not `label_values`.